# Wrapper Function in Python

Tags: python, wrapper

```
#***This code uses wrapper function to print the phone number in a
standard format with country code (if not supplied in the input)***

def ori_func(a):
    mm=[]
    def wraap(*args):
        for k in args:
            for i in k:
                #print(i)
                if len(str(i))==10:
                    mm.append("+91"+str(i))
                elif str(i)[0]=="0" and len(str(i))==11:
                    mm.append("+91"+str(i)[1:])
            #elif len(str(i))==12 and i[0]=="+":
            #    mm.append(i)
                elif len(str(i)) == 12:
                    mm.append("+"+str(i))
                #print (mm)
        return a(mm)
    return wraap

@ori_func
def srt_phone(mm):
    #sorted(int(mm))
    for j in sorted(mm):
        cc=str(j)[:3]
        mmn1=str(j)[3:8]
        mmn2=str(j)[8:]
        print (cc+" "+mmn1+" "+mmn2)

m=[1234567891, 912345678923, +919876543219,"07418529637"]
srt_phone(m)
```

This code works fine as per my knowledge. However I need you to look-through my code and let me know my level of Wrapper function knowledge is correct

1. When I pass a list to wrapper function, do I need to really use 2 "For" loops in wrapper function like I did? Is there any other way?
2. When we asked to get the phone number as input in INT format,how to handle with the input that starts with 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. There are other ways but that way is pretty clean.
2. You can't, and I suggest not treating phone numbers as numbers because they aren't real numbers. Real numbers can't start with a + or a 0.

Your code looks fine to me; I'd have done a few things differently but that's just personal preference. I do recommend that you look into using `@functools.wraps(a)` on your inner function.